# Display custom message while mule project is shutdown

Tags: wsdl, cxf, mule

In MULE CE 3.3.0, I have this Configuration XML file(I copied it below)

```
    <mule xmlns="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core" xmlns:http="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http"
    xmlns:cxf="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/cxf" xmlns:doc="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/documentation"
    xmlns:spring="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:core="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="CE-3.3.0"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http/current/mule-http.xsd 
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/cxf http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/cxf/current/mule-cxf.xsd 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-current.xsd 
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core/current/mule.xsd ">


    <configuration>
        <expression-language>
            <global-functions>
                def parseIp(fullIp) {
                return
                fullIp.substring(fullIp.indexOf('/') + 1, fullIp.indexOf(':'))
                }
        </global-functions>
        </expression-language>
    </configuration>

    <cxf:configuration enableMuleSoapHeaders="false"
        doc:name="CXF Configuration" />
    <flow name="soapservice" doc:name="soapservice">

        <http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response"
            address="http://localhost:8089/services/Echo">
            <cxf:proxy-service service="Weather" payload="envelope"
                wsdlLocation="classpath:myWS.wsdl"

                namespace="http://ws.cdyne.com/WeatherWS/">
                <cxf:inInterceptors>
                    <spring:bean class="org.apache.cxf.interceptor.LoggingInInterceptor" />
                </cxf:inInterceptors>
                <cxf:outInterceptors>
                    <spring:bean class="org.apache.cxf.interceptor.LoggingOutInterceptor" />
                </cxf:outInterceptors>
            </cxf:proxy-service>
        </http:inbound-endpoint>
        <copy-properties propertyName="SOAPAction" />
        <set-variable variableName="remoteClientAddress"
            value="#[parseIp(message.inboundProperties['MULE_REMOTE_CLIENT_ADDRESS'])]" />

        <component doc:name="classTest" class="com.subu.mule.IpClient" />
        <http:outbound-endpoint address="http://wsf.cdyne.com/WeatherWS/Weather.asmx"
            encoding="UTF-8" responseTimeout="1000000" exchange-pattern="request-response">
            <cxf:proxy-client payload="envelope">
                <cxf:inInterceptors>
                    <spring:bean class="org.apache.cxf.interceptor.LoggingInInterceptor" />
                </cxf:inInterceptors>
                <cxf:outInterceptors>
                    <spring:bean class="org.apache.cxf.interceptor.LoggingOutInterceptor" />
                </cxf:outInterceptors>
            </cxf:proxy-client>
        </http:outbound-endpoint>


    </flow>
</mule>
```

After that I run my mule project in browser,I enter `http://localhost:8089/services/Echo?wsdl` then I can see wsdl's code.
But sometimes, my mule project is stop for some reason so when I enter `http://localhost:8089/services/Echo?wsdl` I see this message in browser `could not connect to localhost:8089` **OR** `page could not find`.

I want to control this message, actually when my service(mule project) is down I publish out my custom message that I set it. for example I display this message in browser to clients: **At this time service is down, Try Later !!!!**

Answer (score 1):

In a production environment, that can be achieved by putting a frontend (i.e. a load balancer) that know what to do when the backend server is down.

Instead when you try to connect directly to the backend (i.e. your project running in studio) and this backend is down, is up to the client (i.e. your browser) to display the error message associated with a 404 http error code.

You can find informations about how the 404 http status works [here](http://pcsupport.about.com/od/findbyerrormessage/a/404error.htm)

Comment: Can you introduce me a link, that explain more about it on a sample, Thanks